# Get URL of file after uploading to Firebase with React Native and Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, expo

In my expo project I can upload images to firebase and can view from my firebase console but I want to get the url of that uploaded image how can I get the url my upload function is looks like.

```
uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) =>{
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  // calling firebase storage api
  var ref = Firebase.storage().ref().child("images/posts/"+imageName);
  console.log("*****************firebase***************")
  console.log(ref)
  console.log("*****************firebase***************")
  return ref.put(blob);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getDownloadUrl`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL) method on directly on your *storage reference* to get the result in the form of a **promise**

```
ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => console.log(url))
```

Comment: How to use `url` value and display in `<Tex>`?